# latex to lualatex error at compilation

Tags: luatex, compiling

> Solution: having an up to date system

I've download a template from LaTeXtemplates: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-typographic-thesis

This is a template I want to use but using lualatex. I've start modification of all the document: comment the package not needed, and so on. But I'm done with an error: `l.18 \RequireXeTeX` I don't know wich package need XeTeX.

Here is the log:

```
    This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.60.2-2010070109 (rev 3730)  (format=lualatex 2014.4.15)  21 MAY 2014 09:13
**main
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, farsi, arabic, croatian, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, czech, slov
ak, danish, dutch, finnish, french, basque, ngerman, german, german-x-2009-06-1
9, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ibycus, monogreek, greek, ancientgreek, hungarian, san
skrit, italian, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian2a, mongolian, bokmal, nyn
orsk, romanian, irish, coptic, serbian, turkish, welsh, esperanto, uppersorbian
, estonian, indonesian, interlingua, icelandic, kurmanji, slovenian, polish, po
rtuguese, spanish, galician, catalan, swedish, ukenglish, pinyin, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/scrreprt.cls
Document Class: scrreprt 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script document class (report)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent 
basics and keyval usage)

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent
 basics and keyval usage)

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2009/03/25 v3.03 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Package scrlfile, 2009/03/25 v3.03 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2009/06/08 v3.03b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 117.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 118.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 119.
Class scrreprt Info: You've used standard option `openright'.
(scrreprt)           This is correct!
(scrreprt)           Internaly I'm using `open=right'.
(scrreprt)           If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrreprt)           you'd have to use `open=right' there
(scrreprt)           instead of `openright', too.
Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input l
ine 1271.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script font size class option (11p
t)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (type area)

Package typearea, 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

\ta@bcor=\skip41
\ta@div=\count79
\ta@hblk=\skip42
\ta@vblk=\skip43
\ta@temp=\skip44
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 14.22636pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 408.2971pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -3%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 44.38632pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 0.28453pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 514.20023pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = 12.2347pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.60002pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1115.
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip45
\belowcaptionskip=\skip46
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box26
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./classicthesis-config.tex
\c@dummy=\count89

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2005/01/26 v1.0 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
File: lipsum.dtx 2005/01/26 v1.0 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count90
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
Package: polyglossia 2009/01/25 v1.0.2 Babel replacement for XeLaTeX

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2009/08/06 v1.8 e-TeX tools for LaTeX

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count91
))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2008/08/09 v1.18 Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
! 
 ********************************************
 * XeTeX is required to compile this document.
 * Sorry!
 ********************************************.
\RequireXeTeX ...********************************}
                                                  \endgroup \fi 
l.18 \RequireXeTeX

? x


Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1703 strings out of 256747
 100000,552014 words of node,token memory allocated 253 words of node memory still in use:
   1 hlist, 1 rule, 42 glue_spec, 1 if_stack, 1 write, 1 dir nodes
   avail lists: 2:15,3:1,4:3,5:2,6:31,7:1,9:3,10:3
 5397 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+50000
 15 fonts using 602239 bytes
 36i,1n,48p,848b,48s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,6000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics: 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I can give the modification I made in the config-file if needed

Comment: You have a very old `fontspec`, which used to only support XeTeX. You are going to need to update your system (your LuaTeX is also ancient).

Comment: I know I've not an up to date system but I can't do any update, I'm not root on this computer.

So if I use an up to date system it'll be ok?

Comment: Yes. Why do you want to use LuaTeX here? With a system as old as yours it's going to be tricky: LuaTeX is still be developed and there have been quite a few changes over the years.

Comment: @RomainPicot: Install vanilla TeXLive; you can install it as non-root.

Comment: I'm in an internship and have to make a report at the end of it. I've an up to date system at home but when my code is compiling I try to work a little bit on the report. It's the reason for using this system. So I'll make my output at home if needed

Comment: I've used the same code and command on my computer and it's work perfectly. So I'll install vanilla TeXlive on the other computer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved with a software update